# What are the implications and possible explanations for an AR(7) process model?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, seasonality, lags

I am in the process of constructing a regression for financial data and found that serial autocorrelation is present in the model through the correlogram:

[image]

It looks like it could be an AR(7) process, but could that also indicate that I am failing to model some of the existing dynamics, and as such, they are showing up in this correlogram? I ran my model adding four season dummies, one for each quarter, and found that the model had a lower SIC without seasons. Below is the output with seasons, my current model is just y -> c, time, time.squared.

[image]

I think this is related to the fact that the coefficients are very similar to each other. And it signaled to mean there was no seasonality in the model. However, the AR(7) process seems very strange. Any ideas on where I could be going wrong? Or what this implies?

Comment: Have you done a unit root test? Your series might be non-stationary judging from the slow decay of the ACF.

Comment: Yes I did, and it is stationary after I account for the lags.

Comment: You don't say what "type" of financial data you're modeling or, this is key, the temporal unit of analysis. Are you modeling stock returns? Bond yields? The GDP? You have 380 data points. Is that hourly? Daily? Weekly? Quarterly? Regardless, the higher and more aggregated the temporal unit of analysis is, the greater the likelihood that you're modeling longer term, underlying relationships.

Comment: If a series is auto-correlated lag1 as your is it will also be auto-correlated at other lags. The question as @JohnK pointed out is there additional information at other lags that need to be incorporated i.e. is there evidence of any incremental conditional/partial impact ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case your series is stationary, it would not make sense to fit an AR(7) model though, that would probably be overfitting. Recall that the order of the autoregressive part is determined by the PACF, not the ACF. Thus two lags would be sufficient I believe. The ACF on the other hand is used to indicate the order of the MA process. There are many significant lags here but I believe you can capture the essence by a parsimonious model. If I were you, I would probably begin with something like ARMA(2,0,2) and compare models in that vincinity using the BIC, after of course ensuring that the residuals are white noise.

Comment: I will do that, but the smallest SIC comes from the AR(7) model, doesnt that suggest the model is not over-fitted even using the 7 lags?

Comment: @ANB Which models did you try?

Comment: So I started by modeling trend, found that a quadratic trend best modeled the data (lowest SIC), then ran seasonal dummies on the de-trended data, found that none of them were statistically significant (which seems odd to me), and then added lags to the OLS model with the intercept and quadratic time trend  and saw the 7 lagged model gave me the lowest SIC

Comment: @ANB Did you try ARMA models then?

Comment: No, I didn't, I will try it!

Comment: @ANB Please do what I advised in my answer. Try 2 lags for the AR part and 2 for the MA, use the Ljung Box to ensure the residuals are white noise and modify the lags according to SIC.